# How can I use dataframe instead of rdd for finding manhattan distance measure?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I already written code in Spark rdd like :

```
val result = data.map(x => {
      val eachrecord = x.split(delimiter).map(y => {
        y
      })
      val filterRec = eachrecord.indices.map(x => {
        if(selectedIndex.contains(x)){
          eachrecord(x)
        }
        else{
          ""
        }
      }).filter(x => x!= "").map(y => y.toDouble).toArray
      eachrecord.mkString(delimiter) + delimiter + cendroid.zip(filterRec).foldLeft(0.0) { case (sum, (v1, v2)) => sum + Math.abs(v1 - v2)}
    })
```

here `data` is `RDD[String]`

`selectedIndex` is which columns are belong to this measure.How this can be execute in dataframe? Now I am using Spark 2.3.1.
datasample :

```
   c1,c2,c3,c4,c5
   5.1,3.5,1.4,0.2,0
   4.9,3,1.4,0.2,0
   4.7,3.2,1.3,0.2,0
   4.6,3.1,1.5,0.2,0 
   5,3.6,1.4,0.2,0
   5.4,3.9,1.7,0.4,0
   4.6,3.4,1.4,0.3,0  
   5,3.4,1.5,0.2,0
```

Comment: you can convert RDD to DataFrame using ```.toDF```

Comment: Can you post what's the data actually you have?

Comment: @Sam D , no need to convert the rdd to .toDF , while reading data with Spark 2.3.1 using Spark Session ,its already df .